# unable to load configuration from app:app

Tags: flask, uwsgi

I am trying to run flask app server with uwsgi from supervisor and i getting error

```
[program:tmanalytics]
directory = /srv/www/tmapi/
command = uwsgi --socket /tmp/tmuwsgi.sock   app:app --chmod-socket 777 --touch-reload /srv/www/tmapi/deployment.log
watch=/srv/www/tmapi/app/
stdout_logfile=/srv/www/tmapi/tmapi-analytics.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stopsignal=QUIT
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: app:app not avalaible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
command = uwsgi -s /tmp/tmuwsgi.sock   -w app:app --chmod-socket=666 --touch-reload /srv/www/tmapi/deployment.log
```